# Eliminar el nombre de los elementos de un Array JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json, array, chart.js

Tengo unos datos, que en concreto son las visitas de cada uno de los días durante el último mes. Estos datos están almacenados en una base de datos, y el caso es que los obtengo mediante **PHP** y se me quedan en un **array con 31 elementos**.

Para mostrar los datos en una tabla de estadísticas, uso chart.js, al cual debo pasar los datos de esta forma:

```
data: [173, 104, 190, 143, ...],
```

Eso está en un archivo de JavaScript, donde tengo todo el js de mi sitio web.
Entonces, lo que he hecho es esto:

```
data: chartData,
```

De este modo, tan solo debo hacer un `echo` de la variable `chartData` en PHP con todos los datos, pero el problema es que después de usar `json.encode`, quedan así:

```
data: ["1":173, "2":104, "3":190, ...],
```

Para que el chart.js funcione, debo eliminar el nombre de los elementos y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Entiendo que el último `data` no es un `array`si no más bien un objeto ¿no? Y lo que quieres es pasar de un objeto `{"1": 173, "2":104...}` a `[173, 104...]`, ¿si?

Answer (score 1):

Como buscas pasar de un `object` a un `array` con los valores de las propiedades del objeto, puedes usar la función de javascript:

```js
let data = {"1": 173, "2": 104, "3": 35};
let _data = Object.values(data);
console.log(_data);
```

Obviamente el `array` de data tendrá tantos parámetros como días del mes (31) o los que fuesen necesarios.